# Carga de datos en Formulario - Livewire

Tags: php, bootstrap, laravel-livewire

estoy teniendo problemas con un componente en livewire, el cual le he dado mil vueltas y no he podido resolver

Como podrán ver el metodo que declaré en mi componente se esta llamando efectivamente
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero en el modal no se esta mostrando ninguna información y la verdad desconozco el motivo, si alguien pueda ayudarme con este tema, se lo agradecería mucho.

Les dejo parte de mi código:

```
public $servicios, $name, $description, $service_id;
public $updateMode = false;

private function resetInputFields(){

    $this->name = '';
    $this->description = '';

}

public function getData($id)
{
    $service = Service::where('id',$id)->first();
    $this->service_id = $id;
    $this->name = $service->name;
    $this->description = $service->description;
    $this->is_remote = $service->is_remote;
    $this->is_onsite = $service->is_onsite;

}
```

Mi HTML

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Formula bien tu pregunta y muestra mas codigo. Lo que entiendo es que quieres que muestre la información que está en la bd de datos en un modal?